# How do I make a Button so that when I put part of it out of bounds the program doesn't just cut the parts of it that aren't inbound

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-button

How do I make a Button so that when I put part of it out of bounds the program doesn't just cut the parts of it that aren't inbound. What I mean is this.This is a rotating view, the rectangles are rotating around the circle, but since I put 2 of the buttons partially out of bound their parts get cut off. Is there a quick fix for this?

(If programmatical fix is necessary I am writing in Kotlin)

[image: Image of problem]

Comment: `An issue with Buttons` lots of people have issues with buttons, this doesn't tell me what you're trying to do

Comment: `How do I make a Button so that when I put part of it out of bounds the program doesn't just cut the parts of it that aren't inbound` now this is more likely a better title

Comment: i'm simply trying to help you get an answer :) i've upvoted your question actually, i think it's quite interesting and something others might also research in future, i was simply saying that others wont _find_ it in future with the title as it currently is

Comment: Ok, if that's the issue I will change it.

Comment: yip, not all comments or users are meant to be rude or offensive, this was actually meant to be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the `RelativeLayout` in which you're adding these four `View`s (buttons), has the width of screen's width. You need to increase its width to contain both the left and right buttons completely. Then, when you rotate the `RelativeLayout`, the buttons will be visible.

For testing purpose, try giving this width to `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width = "1000dp"
    android:layout_height = "1000dp">

    <!--Your buttons here-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

See if this works out. If it does, then you'll have to calculate the width of `RelativeLayout` programmatically.